Why does install in a bb class file strip my binary even without the --strip option?
In the .bb file I have the following:
do_install_append() 
{
    install -d "${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}"
    sed -e "s:@bindir@:${bindir}:" -e "s:@datadir@:${datadir}:" \
     "${WORKDIR}/${BPN}_everest.service" \
    >"${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/${BPN}.service"

    bbwarn "Creating folder: ${D}/${bindir} using workdir: ${WORKDIR}"
    install -d "${D}${bindir}"
    install -m 755 "${WORKDIR}/Linux_Daemon_ITS_V4_0_0_0_arm64" "${D}${bindir}"
}

The ITS tool is already stripped and is causing the build to fail with the "already-stripped" error.  I have added in: INSANE_SKIP_${PN}_append = "already-stripped" as recommended and trying this as I type.
But the real question and mystery is to understand why install is stripping the binary? The man page seems to indicate that install will not strip unless explicitly directed to strip and this bb class file is not requesting a strip.
I am using the INSANE_SKIP to get around this issue but just want to understand why install is stripping when not asked to with the --strip option.
